# Impersonate flag causing issues in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

My setup is an MVC website that the user connects to, with a REST Web API service that the website connects to behind the scenes. Both the website and web service need authentication and will use the users Windows authentication first to authenticate, and then to pass this identity to an ADLDS directory claims provider I have to see what they are authorized to perform.

Currently connecting to the MVC website hosted on IIS works fine, the windows credentials are authenticated against and then authorized for permissions and the website behaves fine. But when the website makes the calls to the REST service, the REST service checks for the identity and gets the identity of the app pool, not the credentials of the user calling the MVC website. Ie double hopping problem.

This is with impersonate=false in the web.config of the MVC website. I have tried running the MVC website locally on my box through Visual Studio, connecting to the remotely hosted REST service and set impersonate=true in the local MVC web.config and this works. Ie the REST web service then gets the correct credentials through, not the app pool identity.

However if I set impersonate=true in the web.config of the MVC website hosted on IIS on the remote server, the website fails to load at all. So what works in visual studio, doesn't work when deployed through IIS. The exception I get is

```
01-12-2015 09:52:47,105 [][1] INFO  Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.MvcApplication - **********************APPLICATION STARTED*****************************
01-12-2015 09:53:10,160 [UK\kerslaj1][5] ERROR Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.MvcApplication - System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.IClaimsProvider", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider().
Exception is: TypeInitializationException - The type initializer for 'Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider' threw an exception.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider,(none) (mapped from Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.IClaimsProvider, (none))
  Calling constructor Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider()
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: An operations error occurred.
 ---> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Options()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoApplicationDirectoryInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher.SetDefaultPageSizeForContext()
   at Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider.SetApplicationClaims()
   at Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider.Initialise()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider..ctor()
   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[T](IUnityContainer container, ResolverOverride[] overrides)
   at Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
   at Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.MvcApplication.Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Util.ArglessEventHandlerProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Any suggestions as to why this works on my local machine but not when hosted on IIS?

Comment: what error is logged when impersonate is set to true on the server? have you checked the event viewer on the server for any errors, warnings or standard events logged at the time of the failure?

Comment: First thing I see: 
`Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.IClaimsProvider", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider().
Exception is: TypeInitializationException - The type initializer for 'Centrica.CE.SE.PortalX.Security.ADLDSClaimsProvider' threw an exception.`

Is that DLL available on the server? (Copy Local maybe?)

If that's not it, are you allowed to delegate credential from Website to Webservice?

Comment: The ADLDS claims provider is part of the same assembly so will be on the server. How do I know if I am allowed to delegate credentials?